# Drawing a graph from user input in python

Tags: python, list, if-statement, graph

I am writing a program that takes user input asking for a graph and then prints that graph to the screen with a limit on the axes from -10 to 10. I understand that you're supposed to use this limited range and domain and check that against the graph entered by the user, but I'm struggling with the y-value and getting it to print the coordinates on the graph.

```
import math
y = []

# input the function from the user
func = input ("Enter a function f(x):\n")
print ()

for row in range (10, -11, -1):
    y_value = eval (func.replace ("x", str (row)))
    y.append (y_value)

# where the coord is defined 
for row in range (10, -11, -1):
    for column in range (-10, 11):
        # this is where the program should check for, and output a coordinate
            print ("o", end="")
        if column == 0 and row == 0:
            print ("+", end="")
        elif row == 0:
            print ("-", end="")
        elif column == 0:
            print ("|", end="")
        else:
            print (" ", end="")
    print ()
```

The user input given in the question was x+2, which means the output should be the same as this image

[image: The user input given in the question was x+2, which means the output should be the same as this image]

But what I keep getting is this...

[image: But what I keep getting is this...]

Any comments at all would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your way to go is matplotlib to plot a graph.

Comment: First notice that your list of y values is in reverse order, and its index is offset from the x value used to compute it. If you account for both of those, you should be able to use some variation of "if y[column] == row". I do have a working version, but I don't want to say too much more.

Comment: This makes much more sense, thank you very much!